# How to hide featured image if post have image on wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, image

if there is no media in the post content i want to show featured image. Ive tried below but its not working :

```
.has-post-thumbnail .entry-featured-media.entry-featured-media-main {
    display:none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it can be done via css only.
Found [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60245/get-the-first-image-from-post-content-eg-hotlinked-images) answer to similar problem.

Try this:

add in functions.php:

```
function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

  if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
    $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
  }
  return $first_img;
}
```

Then place the following in your post php (single.php or the template you need):

```
if (!catch_that_image()) {
  if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
  }
}
```

This (`if (!catch_that_image())`) will check if there is no image in the post content.